# Is there a way to put Sitecore Forms fields side by side without CSS

Tags: sitecore-forms, css

While dragging a form field onto the Sitecore Forms canvas, it seems that, there is no way within the interface to add columns of fields eg. two fields side by side.

Is the only way to do this with CSS or is there some functionality within Sitecore Forms (not WFFM) to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no other way, you can do that through CSS only. You can make use of the bootstrap components and create a good UI. For the two columns, you need to make use of the section field.

Make sure you have bootstrap CSS in the head section.

1)  In the form settings [for the form] – provide the CSS class: row

2)  Add Section – In the section CSS Class property enter - form-group col-sm-6 col-xs-12

3)  Add Form Field in the Section that you added. For example: Single-line text and provide the CSS class: form-control

4)  Similarly, for another field, repeat step 2 and 3

I've followed the steps defined here [responsive Sitecore 9 form bootstrap](http://smartsitecore.com/en/responsive-sitecore-9-form-bootstrap/) -- This will help you in setting up a form with fields side by side. Please refer the gif carefully, where it shows, how to add the proper class for fields and field sections.